# Why elements in array dont change after using callback function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I have some problems with understanding how callback function should work. I wanted to do a function that works just like map method. Even though I don't recive any errors, elements in array don't change. Could you point what am I doing wrong?

```
function multiplyFn(x) {
    return x * 2;
}
const exampleArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8];

function mapFn(array, callback) {
    for (const el of array) {
        callback(el);
        console.log(el)
    }
    console.log(array)
    return array;
}

mapFn(exampleArray, multiplyFn);
```

Comment: have you tries running it with debugger?

Comment: They don't change, because you don't change them.  There is no point in your code when you re-assign the result of the callback to the array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change the original array you can update the index of the array arguments that you pass in function.

```
function mapFn(array, callback) {
    array.forEach(function(element,index){
      let val= callback(element)
      array[index] = val
    });
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the elements by the returned values:

```js
function multiplyFn(x) {
    return x * 2;
}
let exampleArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8];

function mapFn(array, callback) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let el = array[i];
        array[i] = callback(el);
    }
    return array;
}

mapFn(exampleArray, multiplyFn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note you can do this simply using Array#map() which will not update original but return a new array

```js
function multiplyFn(x) {
    return x * 2;
}
const exampleArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8];

function mapFn(array, callback) {    
    return array.map(callback);
}

console.log(mapFn(exampleArray, multiplyFn));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement your own map function, you can do it without using any of the in-built array methods

```js
//Define your map method in the Array prototype object

Array.prototype.mymap = function(callback) {
    const res = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
        res[index] = callback(this[index], index, this);
    }
    return res;
}
const exampleArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8];

//Let's test with two examples

function multiplyFn(x) {
    return x * 2;
}
const first = exampleArray.mymap(multiplyFn)
console.log(first)

const second = exampleArray.mymap((el, index, array) => ({el, index}))
console.log(second)
```